# Mocking 3rd party libraries in development

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

What is the elixir way to mock 3rd party libraries.

So during registration I want to send out an email to the user.  In development I want the email module to use a different mock module that would say just output a log trace instead of really sending out an email.

What options are there in elixir for this?
Is this something I can do in the config in phoenix to swap implementations?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the elixir way to mock 3rd party libraries?

### The answer is: *dependency injection*.

---

This [excellent article](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2015/10/mocks-and-explicit-contracts/) by José Valim is a must read; I would quote it all if I could (*the emphasis below is mine*.)

> I will emphasize this later on but I always consider “mock” to be a **noun**, never a **verb**.

and

> when it comes to make the tests pass, a common practice is to just go ahead and mock (**warning! mock as a verb!**) the underlying [...]

---

Also, this [article](https://medium.com/@lasseebert/mocks-in-elixir-7204f8cc9d0f) by Lasse Ebert is worth it to read.

Answer (score 0):

In my personal experience, sometimes it's nice to have a dev instance/workspace/etc that my dev environment hits. Often the only difference between hitting the dev instance and the prod instance is which credentials/URL the API is called with, which makes my prod/dev code exactly the same.

If, however, you would prefer to do dependency injection, you could use the config to point at a dependency. I've never used config this way in production, and it may be bad practice, but it's how I would approach the problem.

Here's an example around `Enum.map/2` & `Stream.map/2`. Let's say your dev config looks like this:

```
# config/dev.exs
config :sandbox, mapper: Enum
```

When you ask for `:mapper`, you get the `Enum` module and can call it like you would directly:

```
iex> Application.get_env(:sandbox, :mapper)
Enum
iex> Application.get_env(:sandbox, :mapper).map(0..2, &Integer.to_string/1)
["0", "1", "2"]
```

Let's say, however, your prod config looks like this:

```
# config/prod.exs
config :sandbox, mapper: Stream
```

When you get `:mapper` in prod (using the same code as in dev), you get the `Stream` module:

```
iex> Application.get_env(:sandbox, :mapper)
Stream
iex> Application.get_env(:sandbox, :mapper).map(0..2, &Integer.to_string/1)
#Stream<[enum: 0..2, funs: [#Function<48.15162342/1 in Stream.map/2>]]>
```

There's a trade-off doing dependency injection this way vs. passing it into every function call: granularity. You don't have to pass it in everywhere, but you are also stuck with whatever you set at compile time.